# SOAP syntax in Powershell 3.0

Tags: .net, web-services, powershell, magento, soap

I'm trying to use Magento's SOAP v2 API (Magento Enterprise, ver 1.12.0.2) to interact with products and their attributes, but our store has a lot of custom attributes to edit. Aside from the default name, description, price, etc., we have additional attributes that I'm having trouble accessing via SOAP v2. I tried using the catalogProductUpdate method to edit attributes ([devdocs page here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.update.html)), but I couldn't understand how to properly set up the "additional_attributes" field to allow editing of custom attributes. I keep getting back an error saying it's not in the correct format. For example, we have music products, so we want to set a value for our "artist" field.

WS-I compliance is not enabled in our Magento.

I'm in Powershell 3.0 using new-webserviceproxy, so I believe that means I'm using .NET framework. So my attempt looks something like this

```
$proxy = new-webserviceproxy -uri $soapuri

$sessionid = $proxy.login($username,$password)

$array1 = @{"key"="artist";"value"="4845"} #I also tried setting the value to the name instead of the ID number (ie. "key" = "artist";"value"="Billy Joel") but that returned the same error.

$array2 = @{"single_data" = $array1}

$proxy.catalogproductupdate($sessionid, <a sku number>, "admin", @{"additional_attributes" = $array2}, "sku")
```

But what returns is an error message saying that the attribute update was not expecting a "system.collections.hashtable". I believe I just have the formatting incorrect regarding the single-data/multi_data nesting. From how I understand it, the additional_attributes parameter's array requires the "single_data" parameter inside it, and inside "single_data" should be the actual attribute listings and values. So altogether it's like a 3-teir hash table.

I am able to use hash table formatting to edit other, non-custom attributes, so I know the problem is not the hash table itself. It's just the "additional_attributes" field.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - finally! Hopefully this saves a future Magento user some trouble. To edit additional attributes, you have to format (from my example) `$array1` using the id number of the attribute and the id number of the attribute value.
So my `$array1` looked like this:
    $array1 = @{"key" = "200";"value" = "4845"}
So "200" is the attribute ID of "artist" in our magento. "4845" is the id of the value I wanted to select (in this case, Billy Joel). So you have to find these values using `catalogProductAttributeList` and that will list all the attribute's ID numbers.

Edit: When I ran this as I just stated, it returned "True" (which should mean it worked) and I immediately went to type this, but then when I looked at the product in Magento it didn't actually update. So I tried a couple different combinations of IDs with words, and what finally worked was the format I have in the original question. I have no idea why that was not working when I tried it the other day, but I swear it works now and I didn't change a thing. My only hypothesis for why this might've happened is I ran the `catalogProductAttributeList` method, and perhaps that somehow created the foundation for the custom attributes that I needed to edit. But all is well now, this answer is void, what works for me is the original example in the question. Wish I had a better explanation.